# How to get python program to read and print with tiered data

Tags: python

I am still a newbie developer with not much time under my belt with this. I have a .csv file that I constructed that contains facility ID, Sequence for the Facility and the NSN for the sequence. I have a .csv that contains every value possible for facility, sequence and NSN along with a a file that just has a facility a lightly structured product that I need. There is a total of 476 different Facilities, 2935 sequences. There are multiple NSNs per sequence but not every sequence has an NSN and not every facility requires a sequence.

What I desire is a .csv output with Facility, Sequence and NSN for every line there is an NSN.

*Data is just simplified examples

```
  Desired Output                                          Input ||||
                                                                VVVV
Facility    Sequence    NSN                                            
                                                                   104b    
104b        22a         55-51a                                         22a
104b        22a         63-42c                              55-51a
104b        24x         55-50a                              63-42c
209c        22a         55-50a                                         24x
209c        39g         63-12L                              55-50a
632f        99Y         44-10q
```

My problem is I only have a rough idea of what needs to be done and I think the direction I am going currently will only produce one facility, sequence, and NSN before moving onto the next facility to repeat.

This is only a rough draft, edits/simple ideas are greatly appreciated, advance suggestions should be explained in great depth on how they work or a complete example, because I would not know what to do with it other wise.

*Note the Quantity is something extra that probably wont make it to the end of dev because it has already been compiled.

def main():
    import os

```
filelist = list()


filewrite = open('NSN.txt', 'w')


class Facility:
'''Represents Facility'''

fileFacilitysource = open ('facility.csv', 'r')

def __init__  (self, facilityID):
    self.FacilityID=facilityID              #facilityID is the facility ID number
    self.SeqList=list()

def AddSeq(self,Seq):
    self.SeqList.append(Seq)

def FindSeq(self,Seq):
    for S in self.SeqList:
        if S.SeqID==SeqIDtoFind:
            return S



class Sequence:
'''Sequence'''

fileSequencesource = open ('sequence.csv', 'r')

def __init__(self,SeqID,ID):
    self.SeqID=SeqID                        #SeqID is the Sequence for the facility             
    self.ID=ID                              #ID is the ID number associated with the Sequence for its place
    self.NSNList=list()

def AddNSN(self,NSN):
    self.NSNlist.append(NSN)



class NSN:
'''NSN'''

fileNSNsource = open ('nsn.csv', 'r')

def __init__ (self,NSNID,QTY):
    self.NSNID=NSNID                        #NSNID is the NSN for the sequence
    self.QTY=QTY                            #QTY is the Quantity associated with the NSN


def Search():

for keywords in fileNSNlist:
            if facility in line:
                if sequence in line:
                    if NSN in line:
print facility, sequence, NSN
                filelist.append(line)                           

TheString = " ".join(filelist)

searchfile.close()

filewrite.write(TheString)

filewrite.close()

main()
```

Comment: was what you posted your input or your desired output? sorry it wasnt clear to me, would help if you could provide both input and desired output

Comment: Please give a standalone example of the input.

Comment: I have edited it to be more clear

Comment: Please get the source code, remove the tabs (suggest indentation at 4 spaces per tabsopt) and ensure the indentation is correct, then paste it into the question.  You can indent it another 4 spaces by selecting all the code and then using the **`{}`** icon above the edit box to indent it all by 4 spaces.  This will leave you with code that looks like workable Python — unlike what's on display at the moment.

Comment: Can you update your question with clear, separate input and output files? The format is not clear.